# Safety of running assertions in a separate execution context

Tags: scala, crash, future, assertion

How isolated are different execution contexts from each other? Say we have two execution contexts `ec1` and `ec2` both used on the same code path implementing some user journey. If, say, starvation and crashing starts happening in `ec2`, would `ec1` remain unaffected?

For example, consider the following scenario where we want to make sure user was charged only once by running an assertion inside a `Future`

```
chargeUserF andThen { case _ => 
  getNumberOfChargesF map { num => assert(num == 0) }
    .andThen { case Failure(e) => logger.error("User charged more than once! Fix ASAP!", e)  } 
}
```

Here `getNumberOfChargesF` is not necessary to fulfil user's request, it is just a side-concern where we assert on the expected state of the database after it was mutated by `chargeUserF`. Because it is not necessary I feel uneasy adding it to the main business logic out of fear it could break the main logic in some way. If I run `getNumberOfChargesF` on a different execution context from the one `chargeUserF` uses, can I assume issues such as starvation, blocking etc. caused by `getNumberOfChargesF` will not affect the main business logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each execution context has its own thread pool, so, yeah ... kinda.
They are "independent" in the sense that if one runs out of threads, the other one might still keep going, however, they do use the same resource (cpu), so if that gets maxed out by one, the other will obviously be affected.

They are also affected by each other's side effects. For example, the way your code is written, `chargeUser` and `getNumberOfCharges` are happening in parallel, and there is no saying which one will finish first, so, if I am guessing the semantics right, the number of charges may end up being either 0 or 1 fairly randomly, depending on whether the previous future has completed or not.